# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (with .css())

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#main").css("column-count":2);
            });
    </script>
```

Console points to this string: `$("#main").css("column-count":2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$("#main").css("column-count",2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma to separate arguments. Change

```
$("#main").css("column-count":2);
```

to

```
$("#main").css("column-count",2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect syntax. Should be:

```
$("#main").css({"column-count":2}); // should use this when more than one property needs to set
```

or

```
$("#main").css("column-count", 2);
```